# Jackson ObjectMapper JSON check for null doesnt work

Tags: java, json, jackson

Currently i'm trying to check if the key value in my json file is null then i will return false, however it doesnt seem to work.

This is my null-checking code

```
jsonGet = ObjectMapper().readTree(//json file);
if(jsonGet.get("key1") == null){
return false; //end program
}
//do something else
```

Tho i set that key value in my json file like so, it also said "key1 => null" in my watch

```
 "key1": null,
```

It somehow doesnt jump into the return false, dont really know what im doing wrong here

Comment: Please edit your question and show the JSON you are trying to parse with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there seem to be some kind of issue regarding getting the null value, so for now i'll just use check instance since the return type is NullNode for some reason

```
if(jsonGet.get("key1") instanceof NullNode){
return false; //end program
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't find here class of `jsonGet` variable. Maybe it's `JsonNode` class. Then `JsonNode.get(String fieldName)` method returns `JsonNode` object ([javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) for JsonNode). Then I think you should use `textValue()` method or smth similar.

But here can be another problem. Maybe you will get String object with value `"null"`. Then you will need to check for this condition (I'm not sure about it).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, tho checkin null by string value doesnt seem like a very logical idea